# Chrome won't open links requested from other apps

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Since the last update, Google Chrome won't open any link when other apps try to open them. It shows an error like this

[image: Google Chrome is Unresponsive. Relaunch Now?]

Clicking either of the button does not do anything.

I can open tabs from an existing tab but the issue happens only when another application tries to open something in the browser.

Chrome Version: `62.0.3202.94` (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, v1703 (15063.483)

I have tried resetting everything in `chrome://flags`

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Chrome fixed this.